# Reviving wool from possible moth damage

Tags: clothing, yarn, technique-selection, wool

I tried hard to find a relevant stackexchange site for this question and this seemed closest.

I have a wool winter jacket that has been stored over summer and on pulling it out of the closet I discovered what looks like, I am guessing, moth damage. See below:

[image]

There are no holes but it seems the “fluff” from the yarn on the herringbone has been removed.

Is there any way to revive the wool and return the texture to the yarn?

Comment: I am sorry to say, the nap texture of the wool cannot be restored, as the very integrity of the tiny wool fibers within the weave has been destroyed in the bare patch. Depending on where the bare area is located on the garment, a patch would be about the only remedy. Sometimes a hole or destroyed surface happens to be in a place where a patch or pocket placement would appear to be a normal design element, such as on an elbow or where a chest pocket would go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick hack would be to roughen up the bare patches with an old toothbrush or the coarse side of a Velcro strip. Try to treat only the bare patches like this, and be extra careful at the edges between areas of original and damaged cloth.

I doubt that you could restore the original properties of the cloth, but that scuffing treatment should make the bare patches less noticeable.

Comment: You are a superstar! Thank-you. Everything you said above was absolutely true. I roughed up the problem spots with velcro and the areas are less noticeable. As you said, it’s not perfect but it no longer looks like I’m walking around with a stained jacket! Thanks.